# This weird stretching is happening with my design, how do I fix it?

Tags: mesh, vertices, subdivision-surface, mirror, shrinkwrap

[image]

I am following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DncP3mKJB2M&t=3778s

as you can see the design is very much looks like the mesh is being stretched to the max even though the vertices for the shrink/wrap modifier is not set to a big offset, I want to fix it, how do I??

Blend file: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your model and the modifiers you applied, changing the Shrinkwrap's Wrap method to "Target Normal Project" option made the texture smooth and not stretched like the below image.

[image]

Comment: thanks wiseman, can you specify why did the nearest point mode didn't work?

Comment: Nearest surface project can be complex as your object on which it was applied has vertices closes to each other. so it will select the nearest target but when you apply Target Normal Project, it points(to the vertices) to the object's normal position and adjusts according to it. You can read more about it on the Blender documentation, that will be a much better explanation.